# Changing the encryption settings of EC2 EBS devices while creating a launch template using AWS CDK with Python

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

In my AWS environment, I have an unencrypted AMI. When I launch EC2 instances from it, their EBS volumes are unencrypted, as expected. I'm trying to change the encryption settings of the EBS volumes to be encrypted at the launch time from this unencrypted AMI. I am using AWS CDK (version 2.66.0) with Python (3.9).

The following code I tested and found that I was able to retrieve the AMI from its name saved in `ami_name`, its `BlockDeviceMappings` and save devices by changing the encryption settings to `true` in to the list variable `ami_block_device_mappings`. However, after adding this to the launch template, the CloudFormation shows the empty list of devices.

**Note:** Please change the value of `ami_name` variable as it applicable for your, if you want to try it.

**mystack.py**:

```
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_ec2 as ec2,
    Stack,
)
from constructs import Construct
import boto3
# import json

class MyStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        ami_name = "MY-TEST-WEB-AMI"

        ec2_client = boto3.client("ec2")

        # Get ami_id from ami_name 
        response = ec2_client.describe_images(
            Filters=[{"Name": "name", "Values": [ami_name]}],
        )
        image = response["Images"][0]
        ami_id = response["Images"][0]["ImageId"]
        
        # Change EBS storage encryption settings, if any
        ami_block_device_mappings = []
        if "BlockDeviceMappings" in image:     
            for mapping in image["BlockDeviceMappings"]:
                if "Ebs" in mapping:
                    mapping["Ebs"]["Encrypted"] = True
                    ami_block_device_mappings.append({"DeviceName": mapping["DeviceName"], "Ebs": mapping["Ebs"]})
        # print(json.dumps(ami_block_device_mappings,indent=4,default=str))

        lt = ec2.CfnLaunchTemplate(
            self, "LaunchTemplate",
            launch_template_data=ec2.CfnLaunchTemplate.LaunchTemplateDataProperty(
                image_id=ami_id,
                block_device_mappings=ami_block_device_mappings
            )
        )
```

**app.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import aws_cdk as cdk
from stacks.my_stack import MyStack

app = cdk.App()
MyStack(app, "MyStack")

app.synth()
```

**Generated Launch Template:**

```
Resources:
  LaunchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateData:
        BlockDeviceMappings:
          - {}
          - {}
        ImageId: ami-0589c6ad4ac8694587
```

What mistakes am making here?

If you have a solution using a different *class* like `ec2.LaunchTemplate` instead of `ec2.cfnLaunchTemplate`, it is still fine, but I am looking for a solution in Python CDK.